Could God sue you?
Let's say someone defames God 491 times. God proceeds to

Contact a local law firm in vision
Hire the law firm to a file lawsuit on His behalf

Would God or the law firm run into any procedural issues?

germany
Defamation needs an "other" as a target. This can be a natural person or legal entity.
If the defamation was against a natural person, like a specific pastor, then they could sue.
If the defamation was against a legal entity, like "The Catholic Church", then they could sue.
Since "God" is neither a natural person, nor a legal entity, they cannot sue (or would have no case at least).


God does not have standing or capacity to sue.

A God, if there is one, can bring about the desired result directly through self-help.



Does the availability of self-help bear on standing? I wouldn't think so, as any defamation plaintiff could theoretically recover damages through self-help. It seems courts tend to discourage that.

@bdb484 They are two independent points in answer to a silly, counterfactual question. And, while courts usually discourage it, the whole practice of having people testify under oath is specifically intended to invoke the fear of direct divine retribution from God, so this would be a special exception to the rules on self-help.

I'd be interested in attending the proceedings. For starters, to prove standing, one might expect to see a proof that the plaintiff does in fact exist.

@ohwilleke Yeah, definitely a bum question. But your answer raised a question I'd never really thought of. If I stole your car but then left it in a public parking lot, would you have standing in a replevin action to recover it? It seems like you should lose that case, but I'm not sure why.

@bdb484 Replevin grants possession to a party that has superior title to the party in possession. But a thief gains no title, even derivative of the true owner. The action would also probably be barred by the doctrine of unclean hands.

@ohwilleke I don't do replevin, so I'll assume you're correct, but the broader questions still stands -- to what extent does the possibility of self-help affect the standing analysis? I don't know, but I think you've spotted a really interesting question.

@bdb484 The possibility of self-help is completely distinct and separate from standing. Standing has more than one part to it, however. There is capacity to sue, and there is individualized injury. "Defaming" God is just another name for blasphemy, which is a crime in some jurisdictions. But how does a God suffer economic damage and why would she subject herself to the jurisdiction of a judge or jury?

I think that analysis might be right; I'm just sort of idly thinking about whether there's any case law addressing it.
